# Mixing pcl versions inside ros?

Tags: ros, pcl, pcl-1.7

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use `RegionGrowingRGB` and other functions which are available in pcl 1.7 but not 1.5. The issue I am having is that 1.7 does not contain the recent patch that was applied to 1.5 (which solved my segfault issue [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/64428/illegal-instruction-when-reading-pcdply-files-readheader/)).

My question is, is there any way I can mix versions in my code? I either want to use 1.5 but be able to call functions implemented in 1.7, or use 1.7 but be able to use the 1.5 version of files which were affected by the patch. Is there any easy way to do this?

I don't think I can simply copy the missing files into the 1.5 directory because I'm sure there are tons of dependencies.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64921/mixing-pcl-versions-inside-ros?/) by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 93 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are trying to use functionality that is only in PCL 1.7, then it is probably in your best interest to apply the patch from your other question to PCL 1.7 and just use that.

I'm going to guess that it will be significantly easier to fix the bug in 1.7 and build from source than it will be to backport all of the functionality to 1.5.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-06-13**:
I was able to get it working by backporting the functions from 1.7 into 1.5. Hopefully there will be a patch to 1.7 before I need to backport any more functions. Thanks anyway.

**Comment by [Shashwat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20233/shashwat/) on 2014-09-18**:
@dberm22! How did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should read http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl17 and use https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/tree/fuerte-unstable-devel.

And if you have any issues with this ros package, then report your problems.

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-06-13**:
I said in my post that I tried 1.7. I updated it 2 days ago..the patch is not applied, so it doesn't work.

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-13**:
Can you give me a link to the patch you talking about? To my knowledge there wasn't any significant change. The problem was just the compiler optimization on the build farm. But I'm wondering if you compile pcl 1.7 yourself, why do you get a "Illegal instruction" error?

**Comment by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) on 2013-06-14**:
https://github.com/ros-gbp/pcl-fuerte-release/commit/1f5e5905b89005fd0e2ffc788eb991900fc9de99 , I think this was all. And this shouldn't make a difference if you compile pcl1.7 yourself.

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-06-14**:
I wasn't sure if that flag was the only difference, so I didn't take the time to download the new source, edit the file, and then recompile myself. Plus, my laptop is a brand new aienware with SSE support...so I have no idea if it'll help.

**Comment by [dberm22](https://answers.ros.org/users/4189/dberm22/) on 2013-06-14**:
Yup, downloading the source, editing the cmake files to not include those checks, and recompiling did the job. Not sure why those flags should matter as my pcl is sse compatible, but either way, it's working.